# touchesMoved detection inside a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, touch

I am trying to detect touches inside a subview

In my main viewcontroller I am adding a subview called:SideBarForCategory, it takes 30% of the screen from the left - as a sidebar.

```
SideBarForCategory *sideBarForCategory = [[SideBarForCategory alloc] initWithNibName:@"SideBarForCategory" bundle:nil];  
[sideBarData addSubview:sideBarForCategory.view];
```

inside SideBarForCategory, I would like to test for touches

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"Map Touch %f",location.x);

}
```

The above code (touchesMoved) works perfectly on the main view (viewcontroller) but does not work inside my subview (SideBarForCategory) - **why and how can I fix it**?

Comment: is your side bar view 'userInteractionEnabled'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions i can think of :

1. Either use GestureRecognizers (eg. UITapGestureRecognizer, UISwipeGestureRecognizer) and add those recognizers to your SideBarForCategory view.
2. Generic gesture handling : Create your own custom subclass of UIView for example MyView and add those touch methods inside it. Then create SideBarForCategory view as an instance of MyView.

Hope it works :)

Updated : 
For second option :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView
@end





@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  // No need to invoke |touchesBegan| on super
  NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  // invoke |touchesMoved| on super so that scrolling can be handled
  [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
  NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
  NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  /* no state to clean up, so null implementation */
  NSLog(@"touchesCancelled");
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Update :
And then in your SideBarCategoryView class implementation , inside loadView()

```
self.view = [[MyView alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hello Yatin, I am targeting ios 4 or better so I am not sure GestureRecognizers is ok, can u elaborate on option 2

Comment: I think GestureRecognizers work good in ios 4 or above. I am myself using it many times. Anyways, it always depends upon the need in a project.

Comment: Yes, it made me change my code, I am not happy of adding yet another view but I can live with it, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

check Apple's references for converting points. You probably forget to convert the point relevant to your subview. Therefore it is trying to check the absolute coordinates of the touch point.

Probably what you need is :

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

Comment: thank, but even if the point is not right the function is not being called at all, I checked it by changing the nslog to NSLog(@"Map Touch");

Comment: Normally the first ones to receive the touches should be the lowest one in the view hierarch therefore you do not need to pass the events. The gesture recognizer solution may be your best option.